# Is it possible to copy an attribute from one XML document to another XML using XSLT/Xpath 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

Trying to copy an attribute from XML 1 to another XML 2  using xslt/xpath. **1-1 combination works but I am having 1 to many combinations between X and Y elements and I keep getting below error.**

XTTE3180: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of
xsl:copy

I am expecting, Y keys from XML1 to be copied to XML2 when the match condition exists. maybe select should be done something differently? Need help with some suggestions.

Comment: Do you have two XML input document XML 1 and XML 2? Or is XML2 the wanted result you want to transform XML 1 to? Anyway, `xsl:copy select` is new in XSLT 3 to create a shallow copy of a single context node and therefore probably is not what you need/want here if you want to output or copy attribute nodes, try `xsl:copy-of select` instead.

Comment: I added both XML1 and XML2 in question. From XML1 I need to copy Y value to XML 2. I think I tried copy-of but still same error.

Comment: So you have two input documents? Where do you use the `doc` or the `document` function to load the second document? Please post minimal but complete code sample to allow us to easily reproduce the error.

Comment: XML2 will be input and XML1 will be pointed as <xsl:param name="XML1" select="doc('XML1.xml')"/> to reference something like this to copy the value. not sure if this helps.

Comment: I don't see any use of a parameter reference `$XML1` in that XSLT sample. Please post the complete stylesheet plus the wanted result sample.

Comment: You don't need to add XML in comments, edit your question and show the wanted output there as a formatted (and if you want to ease our understanding) and indented code block.

Comment: And using `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:copy` certainly doesn't give that error XTTE3180, it will output the selected nodes. I haven't yet understood which nodes you are looking for so I can't tell whether the selection is correct but the error should go away. Do you want to match elements from both input documents based on the `Key` attribute value or are you just adding some values of XML1 to XML2 where you are checking some `Key` based match directly in XML1?

Comment: I just need to copy Y key from XML1 to XML 2. But here it is not 1-1 mapping between X and Y, it is 1-many combination between X and Y which is the problem.

Comment: As I said, the error goes away if you use `xsl:copy-of`, that can output several selected nodes. `xsl:copy select` is an XSLT 3 instruction to make a shallow copy of a single context node.

Comment: Ya I agree, error is gone but I am still not able to get Y key from XML1 copied to XML2. I still see Y key  only.